# Devexpress MVC5 Grid GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex) returns always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress-mvc, onrowclick

Hi everyone I am trying to get the primary key of the selected row to send it to the server later here is the code: 
This the mainpage

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function OnRowClick(s, e) {
        var grid = MVCxClientGridView.Cast(s);
        var key = grid.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex);
        console.log(key);

        $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("FundDetails", "Fund")',
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "text",
          traditional: true,
          data: { rowKey: key },
          success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          },
          error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + '; Status Text: ' + textStatus + 
          '; Error: ' + errorThrown);
          }
          });
           }
    </script>

<div>
@Html.Partial("_FundsList", Model)
</div>
```

And this is the partial view that contains the Grid

```
  @Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
  {

  settings.Name = "FundGrid";
  settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Fund", Action = 
  "FundsList" };
  settings.Width = 450;
  settings.Columns.Add("codeIsin");
  settings.Columns.Add("fundLabel");
  settings.Columns.Add("variation");
  settings.Columns.Add("ClassNiv1");
  settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = true;
  settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectSingleRowOnly = true;
  settings.ClientSideEvents.RowClick = "OnRowClick";
  }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

the problem is that the key value is always null:

*var key = grid.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex);* ==> always Null

PS : *e.visibleIndex* is not null.

Answer (score 1):

The [`GetRowKey`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Scripts.ASPxClientGridView.GetRowKey.method) method explains how null value returned:

> If the index passed via the visibleIndex parameter is wrong, **or the
>   ASPxGridBase.KeyFieldName property is not set**, null is returned.

It is possible that you need to set [`KeyFieldName`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.Mvc.GridSettingsBase.KeyFieldName.property) which refers to primary key and/or identity field (with unique value) in the `GridView`, like this example:

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "FundGrid";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Fund", Action = "FundsList" };
    settings.Width = 450;
    settings.Columns.Add("codeIsin");
    settings.Columns.Add("fundLabel");
    settings.Columns.Add("variation");
    settings.Columns.Add("ClassNiv1");

    // set primary/identity key field to determine selected row index
    settings.KeyFieldName = "codeIsIn";

    settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = true;
    settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectSingleRowOnly = true;
    settings.ClientSideEvents.RowClick = "OnRowClick";
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Also you can put null value checking with `if` condition before executing AJAX call to ensure key field value passed properly:

```
var key = grid.GetRowKey(e.visibleIndex);

if (key != null)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("FundDetails", "Fund")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { rowKey: key },
        // other AJAX settings
        success: function (data) {
            // do something
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // error handling
        }
    });
}
```